# Does the word "negotium" literally mean "not otium"?

Tags: etymology, meaning, noun

Spanish word *ocio* (English: 'leisure') and *negocio* (English: 'business` among other meanings) come from Latin *otium* and *negotium*. Spanish *ocio* also gave *ocioso*, as in *estar ocioso* (English: 'to be idle' or 'unoccupied'). And a possible meaning of *negocio* in Spanish is 'occupation'.

So it seems that both words are somewhat related, as *negotium* seems to be something like *not otium*. Is that so? Has that *neg-* prefix something to do with *negāre* or *negatio*?

Answer (score 4):

From de Vaan's etymological dictionary:

> otium 'spare time, relaxation' [n. o] (P1.+)  Derivatives: otiosus 'at
>   leisure, inactive' (P1.+); negotium 'work, business, 1 difficulty'
>   (PI.+), negdtiolum 'little business, slight difficulty' (P1.+),
>   negotiosus 'occupied, busy' (PI.+).
>
> For otium, an etymology involving *au- is unattractive, since there is
>   no evidence for
>   *au-. Benveniste 1951 argues that negotium must have been a nominal cp. *nec-otium from the start, with the meaning 'non-loisir', that is,
>   'obstacle, empechement'. It would have been a Latin calque on Gr.
>   ἀσχολία 'absence of spare time', 'occupation'. This leaves unanswered
>   the question of why the Romans not translate the Gr. word as
>   *in-otium. The word remains without etymology.  Bibl.: WH II: 157,228f„ EM 436,471.

Comment: I've just read in a Spanish etymology book by Joan Corominas that _negocio_ is indeed a "negative derivative of _otium_", but does not go more in depth about it.

Comment: @Charlie. Yes, but don't "confirm" something from a book published in 2008 by referring to one published in the 1950s.